# Undesirable Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

In a title *"Forcing a Garbage Colection"* from book *"C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform"* by Andrew Troelsen written:

"Again, the whole purpose of the .NET garbage collector is to manage memory on our behalf. However, in some very rare circumstances, it may be beneficial to programmatically force a garbage collection using GC.Collect(). Specifically:

•  Your application is about to enter into a block of code that you don’t want interrupted by a possible garbage collection.
...
"

But stop! Is there a such case when Garbage Collection is undesirable? I never saw/read something like that (because of my little development experience of course). If while your practice you have done something like that, please share. For me it's very interesting point.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do take special note of *"some very rare circumstances"* and do not sprinkle GC.Collect() all over your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run a recipe related website, and I store a massive graph of recipes and their ingredient usage in memory.  Due to the way I pivot this information for quick access, I have to load several gigs of data into memory when the application loads before I can organize the data into a very optimized graph.  I create a huge amount of tiny objects on the heap that, once the graph is built, become unreachable.

This is all done when the web application loads, and probably takes 4-5 seconds to do.  After I do so, I call `GC.Collect();` because I'd rather re-claim all that memory now rather than potentially block all threads during an incoming HTTP request while the garbage collector is freaking out cleaning up all these short lived objects.  I also figure it's better to clean up now since the heap is probably less fragmented at this time, since my app hasn't really done anything else so far.  Delaying this might result in many more objects being created, and the heap needing to be compressed more when GC runs automatically.

Other than that, in my 12 years of .NET programming, I've never come across a situation where I wanted to force the garbage collector to run.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there's absolutely a case when garbage collection is undesirable: when a user is waiting for something to happen, and they have to wait longer because the code can't proceed until garbage collection has completed.

That's Troelsen's point: if you have a specific point where you know a GC *isn't* problematic *and is likely to be able to collect significant amounts of garbage* then it *may* be a good idea to provoke it then, to avoid it triggering at a less opportune moment.

Comment: Whe you know it isn't problematic, even rarer than scenarios where you might want to...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: It's relatively rare, but not unheard of. More accurately, you may well know that it's *less* problematic now than it would be soon.

Comment: THere's always a reason to break the rules, not arguing that you should never do that, just that before you break them, you should understand them, so you can break them effectively.

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation is that you should not explicitly call `Collect` in your code. Can you find circumstances where it's useful?

Others have detailed some, and there are no doubt more. The first thing to understand though, is **don't do it**.   It's a last resort, investigate other options, learn how GC works look at how your code is impacted, follow best practices for your designs.

Calling `Collect` at the wrong point will make your performance worse. Worse still, to rely on it makes your code very fragile. The rare conditions required to make a call to `Collect` beneficial, or at last not harmful, can be utterly undone with a simple change to the code, which will result unexpected OOMs, sluggish performamnce and such.

Answer (score 2):

I call it before performance measurements so that the GC doesn't falsify the results.

Another situation are unit-tests testing for memory leaks:

```
object doesItLeak = /*...*/; //The object you want to have tested
WeakReference reference = new WeakRefrence(doesItLeak); 
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();

Assert.That(!reference.IsAlive);
```

Besides those, I did not encounter a situation in which it would actually be helpful.
Especially in production code, `GC.Collect` should never be found IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very rare, but GC can be a moderately expensive process so if there's a particular section that's timing sensitive, you don't want that section interupted by GC.

Answer (score 1):

> Your application is about to enter into a block of code that you don’t
>   want interrupted by a possible garbage collection. ...

A very suspect argument (that is nevertheless used a lot).

Windows is not a Real Time OS. Your code (Thread/Process) can always be pre-empted by the OS scheduler. You do not have a guaranteed access to the CPU.

So it boils down to: how does the time for a GC-run compare to a time-slot (~ 20 ms) ?

There is very little hard data available about that, I searched a few times.

From my own observation (very informal), a gen-0 collection is < 40 ms, usually a lot less. A full gen-2 can run into ~100 ms, probably more.

So the 'risk' of being interrupted by the GC is of the same order of magnitude as being swapped out for another process. And you can't control the latter.